# Let E be a compact metric space, Prove a family of real-valued continuous function $\mathscr{F}\subset\mathscr{C}(E)$ is dense in $\mathscr{C}(E)$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let E be a compact metric space, assume that a family of real-valued continuous function $\mathscr{F}\subset\mathscr{C}(E)$ satisfies the following two contions:

(i)For every $x,y\in E$ and $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$,there exist a function $f\in\mathscr{F}$ such that $f(x)=a$ and $f(y)=b$

(ii)If $f,g\in\mathscr{F}$,then the functions $\max\{f,g\}$ and $\min\{f,g\}$ lie in the closure $\overline{\mathscr{F}}$

Prove the $\mathscr{F}$ is dense in $\mathscr{C}(E)$

I think this quesetion may use the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem, but I can't figure out how to use (i) to obtain seperates points ($\forall x\neq y\in E$,exist $f\in\mathscr{F}$ s.t. $f(x)\neq f(y)$). I guess (ii) may get $f*g\in\mathscr{F}$, but how to prove $f*g\in\mathscr{F}$ also make me confused.

Comment: Given $x \ne y \in E$, choose $a \ne b$ and use (i), then the seperation condition is satisfied.

Comment: And also, $\mathscr{F}$ in this question may not be a subalgebra (even if we replace $\overline{\mathscr{F}}$ with $\mathscr{F}$ in (ii) ) - consider $E=[-1,1]$ and $\mathscr{F}$ be all piecewise linear functions on $E$.

Comment: I mean you may try to prove that $\overline{\mathscr{F}}$ (not $\mathscr{F}$) is a subalgebra because there is closedness.

Comment: Thanks for your answer very much. does it mean in the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem,if we can prove that $\overline{\mathscr{F}}$ is a subalgebra, we can also obtain the same conlusion?

Comment: Yes, because (i) implies both seperation condition and non-vanishing condition.